# Running python file on command line?

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have a python script "program.py" that takes 2 command line arguments.

When I want to run this program on command line, I should enter:

```
./python myprogram.py arg1 arg2
```

However, I want to run my script without the "python" and ".py"

In other words, I want to do this:

```
./myprogram arg1 arg2
```

I've written a shell script "myprogram.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
python myprogram.py
```

But I still have to run this by typing

```
./sh myprogram.sh arg1 arg2
```

which is still not what I want

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: did you make it executable? http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable-on-unix.htm

Answer (score 3):

As the first line of `myprogram.py`, put the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then, at the command line, in the same directory as `myprogram.py`, enter the following commands:

```
mv myprogram.py myprogram
chmod +x myprogram
```

And you're all set!

Answer (score 1):

Put a shebang at the beginning of your script, something like

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

The file extension is of no matter whatsoever. So just name your file "program" instead of "program.py".

Then give yourself the right to execute it

```
chmod +x myprogram
```

Or make it executable for everybody:

```
chmod a+x myprogram
```

Then call it from the shell

```
./myprogram arg1 arg2
```

---

Here a full example:

```
$echo "#! /usr/bin/env python
> print('Here be dragons.')" > program
$chmod +x program
$./program
Here be dragons.
$
```